# Why the same version work perfectly on TestFlight but getting "Invalid binary" on App Store?

Tags: xcode, react-native, app-store-connect, testflight

I've a React Native app deployed on TestFlight, but now I went to publish the same app on App Store.
Should I deploy the same version, or I should create a new archive with Xcode with a new build number and new version number ?

And why the same version work on TestFlight and not on App Store ?

I tried to submit the app on App store for review, but I'm getting "invalid binary" error. But the same version work perfectly on TestFlight.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s working perfectly on TestFlight and you happy with that version. Would you not use the same bundle in your release? Can read more at [apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-builds/choose-a-build-to-submit).

However, you are probably going to have to deal with that error at some point. Check your email. Should provide more detail of what the issue actually is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my version deployed on TestFlight is using iOS SDK 15.2, but to deploy a new version on App Store it must be built with iOS 16 16.1 or later.

I discover this when I tried to build a new version of my app with Xcode, so I ended up updating my Xcode to 14.1 to get iOS 16.1.